# Error Reporting with App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I'm having troubles getting the Google Stackdriver Error Reporting to work using an App Engine Flexible Environment w/ Python 2.7

The documentation says a flexible environment requires manual configuration: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setting-up-on-app-engine

By default with the python runtime, it looks like google-fluentd is installed because `ps ax | grep fluentd` returns what the docs suggest. However, doing a `sudo service google-fluentd restart` fails.

I have `fluent-logger==0.4.1` in my requirements.txt file.

I switched to a custom runtime to be able to place the `forward.conf` file in `/etc/google-fluentd/config.d` where the docs suggest.

My Docker file looks like this:

```
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/python
RUN virtualenv /env -p python2.7

# stackdriver logging (for error reporting)
RUN mkdir -p /etc/google-fluentd/config.d
ADD forward.conf /etc/google-fluentd/config.d/    

# Set virtualenv environment variables. This is equivalent to running
# source /env/bin/activate
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /app/
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
RUN python manage.py migrate --noinput

CMD gunicorn -b :$PORT project_name.wsgi
```

and forward.conf looks like:

```
<source>
  type forward
  port 24224
</source>
```

In my app I have a view that should report the error, but nothing comes through:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

from fluent import sender
from fluent import event
import traceback

sender.setup('myapp', host='localhost', port=24224)


def report(ex):
    data = {}
    data['message'] = '{0}'.format(ex)
    data['serviceContext'] = {'service' : 'myapp'}
    # ... add more metadata
    event.Event('errors', data)


class ErrorView(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # report exception data using:
        try:
            Exception("Woops.. an Error Occurred")
        except Exception as e:
            report(traceback.format_exc())
            raise e
```

Is there something I'm missing with the setup? The web server access logs come through just fine, but not exceptions or writing out to stderr or stdout

### Update 5/9/2016

Thanks to @Steren's answer... it is much simpler than I made it out to be with Django in the Python Flexible Environment. There is no need for a custom runtime and installing `fluentd`. Below is a working sample that outputs a file log to `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/error.log` and a log formatter to put the log in the appropriate format.

LOGGING Settings:

```
    'formatters': {
        'gcp_json': {
            '()': 'helloworld.gcp_logger.GCPJsonFormatter',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/errors.json',
            'formatter': 'gcp_json',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    },
```

and the formatter:

```
    import logging
    import json
    import os


    class GCPJsonFormatter(logging.Formatter):

        def format(self, record):
            # https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages
            return json.dumps({
                'eventTime': record.created,
                'message': self.formatException(record.exc_info),
                'level': record.levelname,
                'serviceContext': {


          'service': os.environ.get('GAE_MODULE_NAME', ''),
                'version': os.environ.get('GAE_MODULE_VERSION', ''),
            },
            "context": {
                "httpRequest": self._get_request_info(record),
                'user': str(record.request.user) if record.request else "",
                "reportLocation": {
                    "filePath": record.pathname,
                    "lineNumber": record.lineno,
                    "functionName": record.funcName,
                },
            }
        })

    def _get_request_info(self, record):
        try:
            request = record.request
            return {
                "method": request.method,
                "url": request.get_full_path(),
                "userAgent": request.META.get("HTTP_USER_AGENT", ""),
                "referrer": request.META.get("HTTP_REFERER", ""),
                "responseStatusCode": record.status_code,
                "remoteIp": request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR", "")
            }
        except Exception:
            return {}
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, I am the Stackdriver Error Reporting product manager.
Can you confirm you see the reported errors in the Logs viewer as structured payload? If so, what is the name of the log stream?

Comment: Hi @Steren  I see the access logs in the log viewer, but the errors do not appear in the Logs viewer the way they do in the standard environment. The standard environment shows a chunk of the stack trace (and anything specific that was logged) which is really handy.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes indeed, flexible environment does not support request logs, we are working on making Error Reporting easier to setup in flexible.
Do you see the stacktrace in any Log stream? If not, this is the first step. I will try to publish by next week the instructions to make it work on Node.js, they should be adaptable easily for Python.

Comment: @Steren - I'm not able to see the stack trace in any log streams I don't believe. Where can I watch out for your instructions with Node.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to configure the App Engine flexible runtimes without requiring a custom runtime, it will soon be documented on the official documentation, and we are also working to make these steps simpler:

You should use similar code as the one detailed in the [Google Compute Engine samples](https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/setting-up-on-compute-engine#send_exception_data) to send exception data as structured logs into a file named `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/errors.json` (do not send them via a TCP port)

It is important that:

- The file path starts with `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/`
- The file extension is `.json`
- The file name contains `err` in the name.
- The file only contains structured JSON objects.

You can then confirm in Stackdriver Logging that you see the errors appearing as `structPayload` in a custom log stream:
Pick `App Engine` in the first dropdown, and then `custom.var.lop.app_engine.app.custom_logs.errors.json`.

If this is the case, then Error Reporting should automatically starts processing these errors.

Let me know if it is not the case.

Comment: Thanks, that extremely helpful and lets me see the errors in Stackdriver Logging! I still don't see it in Error Reporting though.. does it take a while to start, or is there other structure I might need in the JSON structure?

Comment: The file name I'm using is: `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs/errors.json` When I ssh into the box, the logs appear to truly be located at `/var/log/app_engine/app/custom_logs/errors.json`

Comment: Is the JSON payload following the one described on this page: https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/docs/formatting-error-messages. The message field should contain a stack trace.

Comment: Oh got it.. I didn't realize the message had to be a stack trace. Works fantastic. Thank you so much for all your help!